# How to get Distinct Email ID with muiltiple records where ID=@ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, unique, distinct

I am getting the list of ID and On behalf of that ID I am getting the list of records I am attaching the records details in a image
[image]

as you see in the image I am getting duplicate  Email ID, so for making email id unique I used this query
Here is my query

```
 WITH cte AS
(   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY ID Desc) AS rn
    FROM AlertsTbl
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

so I am getting unique email ID by this but the problem is how can I pass  the Id which was selected in the image to show records which have only unique email address?

Comment: Could you show us some sample and expected result?  Sounds like `WHERE ID = @ID GROUP BY Email HAVING COUNT(1) = 1`

Comment: Do you want records that have unique email?

Comment: yes sir records having unique email

Comment: SELECT * FROM AlertsTbl
WHERE Email IN (
SELECT Email
FROM AlertsTbl
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)

Comment: Too small, I can't read that image.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, i understood your question correctly.

Tried to create similar scenario. I think below query might help.

Sqlfiddle link - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8419b/1/0

```
WITH cte AS
(  
SELECT email ,
 id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Email ORDER BY ID Desc) AS rn , 
 count(email) over (PARTITION BY Email) cnt
    FROM so_test
  )
  SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE cnt = 1;
```

Comment: How should I passed ID in above query

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand. Please explain what you want to say

Comment: yes sir i want to get the unique email IDs on the behalf of the ID which was shown in attached image.

Comment: Sorry, image is not clearly visible. Can you please paste your expected output. It will really help me as well as others to understand the question in better way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM AlertsTbl
WHERE Email IN (
SELECT Email
FROM AlertsTbl
GROUP BY Email
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is little bit confusing. You want to get distinct email id for individual ID. But you have stored duplicate email id's for multiple ID. If you pass one ID then you will get one Email ID. 
If you want only distinct Email id then you can use

```
Select Distinct(EMail) FROM AlertsTbl
```